# LINQ Join,how to impose condition

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have two lists(`First` and `Second`)

```
Id  Value
1   A
2   B
3   C

Id  NewValue
1   a10
1   a21
1   a61
2   b71
2   b79
3   c40
3   c48
3   c55
```

I want to perform join query

```
from p in First
join c in Second on p.Id equals c.Id
select new { p.Value, c.NewValue }
```

But I also want to impose condition on numerical part of `NewValue`,to choose that one that are greater than 40.Only a61,then b71 and so on.
How to modify my join query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it on the `join` condition but add a `where` clause:

```
from p in First
join c in Second on p.Id equals c.Id
where int.Parse(c.NewValue.Substring(1)) > 40
select new { p.Value, c.NewValue }
```

Note that you might want to work with `int.TryParse` and verify that the parsing succeeded

Comment: @GiladGreen Can you explain c.NewValue -2?Thanks.

Comment: @R.SImovic - see update. As Tim suggested easier the other overload and also it was a mistake - should have been `c.NewValue.Length - 1`

Comment: Regarding your suggestion: do not attempt to use anything that mutates a variable via an out parameter in a query; it can lead to bizarre situations.  What you want to do instead is write a helper: `public static int? ToInteger(this string s) => int.TryParse(s, out var i) ? (int?)i : (int?)null;` Now you can use `c.NewValue.Substring(1).ToInteger() > 40` which will be false if it returns null.